# Memcpy from a double pointer in c

Tags: c, pointers, memcpy

I have a pointer `A`, which is passed into a function with address, say `myfunc(&A)`.

In the function `myfunc(char **A) { 
I want to copy memory from A[2 to n] to C[2 to n] }`

I tried `memcpy(&c[2], &(*A)[2], 20);`
I am getting the address copied into `c` rather than the actual info in `A`.

Comment: provide a bit more background (code, for example)

Comment: maybe you could post a piece of code and describe what data should be copied. The question is not clear to me at the moment

Comment: If you does not want to change the value of `A` in `myfunc()`, why do you pass the address of `A`?

Comment: @leeduhem, I wanted to change A, and I wanted to copy A to another variable C, thats all

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt All I wanted is to copy A to another variable C, in the function myfunc. I tried the following way, but the job is not done.

Comment: `memcpy(c+2, *A+2, 20)` should be enough.

Comment: @leeduhem dude it dint work either

Comment: @user1518989 Please refer to my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`memcpy(c+2, *A+2, 20)` should be enough.

Here is a test program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char c[10] = { 'a', 'b' };

void myfunc(char **A)
{
    memcpy(c+2, *A+2, 8);
}

int
main(void)
{
    char *A = "ABCDEFIJK";
    printf("Before: %s\n", c);
    myfunc(&A);
    printf("After : %s\n", c);
    return 0;
}
```

Run:

```
$ ./a.out 
Before: ab
After : abCDEFIJK
```

Answer (score 1):

To copy memory from A[2 to n] to C[2 to n] (from question)

`A` is a `char **`, it points to a number of `char *`.
The 3rd `char *` is `A[2]`. You want to use the address of that element in *memcpy*. 
So the line should be

```
memcpy(&c[2], &A[2], N);
```

where *N* is, according to your text, `(n-2+1)*sizeof(char *)`. *memcpy* size argument ignores the type of what it copies, therefore the total size of what to be copied is to be provided. You want to copy from `2` to `n`, that makes `n-2+1` elements. Each element is a `char *` which size is `sizeof(char *)`.

-- *following comment* --

While not clear from the question, if you want to dereference `A` twice, you copy characters... like

```
memcpy(&c[2], &A[0][2], 20 /* 20 chars */);
```

`C` would be a `char *`.

Comment: it didnt work and btw A[2] is incorect, it should be (*A)[2] as far I know, and (*A)[2] is the pointer to the pointer (A +2).

Comment: This is to copy memory from A[2 to n] to C[2 to n], per the question. Please see edited answer anyway (following comment).